# no viable alternative at input - ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm creating a grammar to read a text file, but it gives always the same error: no viable alternative

ANTLR:

```
  prog: stat+ ;
  stat: expr NEWLINE #assign
 | NEWLINE # blank
  ;

 expr: ID ASPAS titulo ASPAS genero ANO_LANCAMENTO DURACAO expr
   | ID ASPAS titulo ASPAS genero ANO_LANCAMENTO DURACAO
   ;

 ID : [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'-'[0-9][0-9]'.'[a-zA-Z0-9];

  //etc
```

And this is the file that contains the tokens

```
ABC-12.3 "MadMax O Movie" ACAO,FICCAO 2015 02:01
XXX-01.3 "Aloha" COMEDIA,ROMANCE 2015 01:45
```

and here is the output:

```
 line 1:9 no viable alternative at input 'ABC-11.9 '
 line 2:9 no viable alternative at input 'XXX-01.3 '
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please post the full grammar?

Comment: do you have whitespace rule defined to skip? 'ABC-11.9 ' -> the space there is weird...

Answer (score 0):

Could we have the full grammar as the provided lines do not address what may be the issue but the error you are receiving is simply because your files text does not Match any rule set structure specified in the grammar